# How to describe formula as "for each" over some set?

Tags: functions, algorithms, transformation

What are the math symbols used to describe an operation that simply transforms each element in some input set?

For example, the operation takes each element, squares it, and subtracts itself.

```
function someOperation(set) {
   return set.forEach((element) => {
      return element * element - element;
   });
}
```

Comment: it is just a function, in your example it is $f(x)=x^2-x$, then the image set can be noted as $f(\Bbb R)$ supposing that the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is about. Let be $A$ the set, your function someOperation(set) maps $A$ to $\{x^2-x~:~x\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to specify using set notation along the lines of 
$\{i^2-i, \text{for }i \in A\}$.  Often, you'll see the word for replaced by a colon
$\{i^2-i : i \in A\}$

Comment: $A \cdot A = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \ne [a_1^2,a_22^2,...,a_n^2]$ !!

Comment: Yes, I had something else in mind. Updated